# vue-chat-scroll not scrolling to the last message in the list

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I have a chat feature in my `vue` app.The message are loaded in a list as the following.

```
        <div class="chat">
          <ul v-chat-scroll>
              <li 
              v-for="message in messages" 
              :key="message.id"
              :class="message.from == 'a' ?  'message-card-left' : 'message-card-right'"
              >
              <Card class="message-card">
                  <template slot="content">
                  {{message.message}}
                  </template>
                  <template class="message-time" slot="footer">
                  {{message.time}}
                  </template>
              </Card>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

The messages variable looks like:

```
  messages: [
              {
                id: 1,
                from: 'a',
                to: 'b',
                message:'time',
                time: '1:00'
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                from: 'b',
                to: 'a',
                message:'time',
                time: '1:00'
              },
            ]
```

I removed the other objects for readability. I want `v-chat-scroll` to scroll the chat window to the last message. I am using `primeVue` in this code too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. The `v-chat-scroll` directive should be  on the `ul` with the class `.chat` in my case that makes the chats scroll able.
So the following code fixed the problem:

```
<div>
      <ul class="chat" v-chat-scroll>
          <li 
          v-for="message in messages" 
          :key="message.id"
          :class="message.from == 'a' ?  'message-card-left' : 'message-card-right'"
          >
          <Card class="message-card">
              <template slot="content">
              {{message.message}}
              </template>
              <template class="message-time" slot="footer">
              {{message.time}}
              </template>
          </Card>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```